# Pasar variable File de js a php y guardar el archivo

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Muy buenas, se me ha presentado una situación en la que mediante un `input type="file"` he de recoger un fichero que el usuario me ha de facilitar.

Una vez tengo el fichero como variable `File` necesitaría guardarme ese fichero facilitado en una ruta dentro de las carpetas de la web.

No se si eso es posible utilizando íntegramente JavaScript, por lo tanto también había pensado en enviar la variable al servidor mediante un **POST a PHP** y después desde allí procesarla y guardar el archivo para mas tarde poder recuperarlo.

La cuestión es que no he logrado realizar el paso de enviar la variable (o su contenido) al servidor mediante POST y una vez lo lograse tampoco sabría que hacer con estos datos para generar un archivo mediante ellos.

Habría alguna forma para poder enviarme esa variable File a PHP y una vez allí guardar el archivo en una ruta X? O en su defecto de algúna solución para poder almacenar ese fichero que me esta siendo facilitado.

Pongo el código de lo que he realizado hasta el momento.

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('oculto').click()"> Agregar </a>

<input type="file" id="oculto" onChange="funcion1(this.id)" hidden >
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function funcion1(id) {
    var ficheros = document.getElementById(id).files;
    var fichero = ficheros[ficheros.length - 1];
    var nombre = fichero.name;

    jQuery.post("includes/guardaArchivoRegDocu.php", { 
        tFile: fichero,
        tNombre: nombre,
        tProve: prove
        }, function(data){
            alert(data);
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$empresa = "";
$file = "";
$nombre = "";
$prove = "";

if (isset($_COOKIE["empresaID"])) $empresa=$_COOKIE["empresaID"];
if (isset($_POST['tFile'])) $file = $_POST['tFile'];
if (isset($_POST['tNombre'])) $nombre = $_POST['tNombre'];
if (isset($_POST['tProve'])) $prove = $_POST['tProve'];

if (!file_exists("../Contabilidad/Documentos/Proveedores/".$prove)) {
    mkdir("../Contabilidad/Documentos/Proveedores/".$prove, 0700);
}

file_put_contents("../Contabilidad/Documentos/Proveedores/".$prove."/text.txt", $file);

?>
```

Hasta el momento lo único que he llegado a realizar desde PHP (dado que no he logrado recibir el fichero) es hacer pruebas de crear los directorios y un archivo de pruebas.

Cualquier ayuda viene bien.

Comment: Para recoger el archivo desde JS y pasarlo al servidor puedes usar Ajax o bien la nueva API Fetch. Si el archivo es recogido desde un formulario el mismo debe ser declarado como `multipart`. En cuanto al servidor, la super global para recuperar los archivos es `$_FILES`, no  `$_POST`. Sugeriría que pongas en marcha tu código, primero eligiendo qué herramienta usarás para recuperar/enviar tu archivo desde el cliente (hay varias preguntas aquí que tratan ese tema y si te decides por `fetch` la documentación es bastante clara). Si tienes algún problema concreto puedes preguntar aquí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Básicamente estás cometiendo tres errores, el primero es que para recoger archivos tipo `FILE` desde javascript, debes hacerlo usando un objeto `FormData`. El segundo error es que dentro de tu función AJAX, debes especificar el `contentType` y el `processData` como falsos, para que el `FormData` se envíe correctamente. Y el tercer error es que en PHP, las variables tipo `FILE` no se reciben con `$_POST`, se reciben con `$_FILES`.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como debería quedar tu código:

```js
function funcion1(id) {

  let fichero = $('#oculto')[0].files[0];
  let nombre = fichero.name;

  let datos = new FormData();
  datos.append('tFile', fichero);
  datos.append('tNombre', nombre);
  datos.append('tProve', prove);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/guardaArchivoRegDocu.php",
    data: datos,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(r) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<?php
$empresa = "";
$file = "";
$nombre = "";
$prove = "";

if (isset($_COOKIE["empresaID"])) $empresa=$_COOKIE["empresaID"];
if(isset($_FILES['tFile'])) $file = $_FILES['tFile']; // CAMBIO REALIZADO
if(isset($_POST['tNombre'])) $nombre = $_POST['tNombre'];
if(isset($_POST['tProve'])) $prove = $_POST['tProve'];

if (!file_exists("../Contabilidad/Documentos/Proveedores/".$prove)) {
    mkdir("../Contabilidad/Documentos/Proveedores/".$prove, 0700);
}

file_put_contents("../Contabilidad/Documentos/Proveedores/".$prove."/text.txt", $file);

?>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```